# Bootstrap or Skeleton Column Widths - How their Widths Decided

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, skeleton-css-boilerplate

In Bootstrap or Skeleton, how are the various column widths decided?

For eg: In Bootstrap,  .col-md-1 has width 8.33333333%.

And in Skeleton width of 1 column is 4.66666666667%.

Are they taken just randomly just by thinking or there is some science behind it?

Thank you

Comment: 100% / 12 = ~8.33333333%

Comment: What about Skeleton. Width of 1 column in skeleton is 4.66666666667%

Comment: For skeleton, it looks like there is a lot more  padding between the columns that could account for the disparity between the two % values.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind the 8.33% is maths. Bootstrap by default has 12 columns so:

```
100/12 = 8.3333333
```

If you visit the Bootstrap website and [customise](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) the number of columns, that percentage will change. For example, if you choose 10 columns (i.e. change the `@grid-columns` value) the width will instead become 10%.

Comment: Thank you it helped a bit. What about Skeleton. Width of 1 column in skeleton is 4.66666666667%

Answer (score 0):

I've been answering this question a lot recently so I made this which might help explain what's going on: https://github.com/mattdell/bootstrap-grid-demo

But essentially it depends on whether you're using a container or a container-fluid. If you are using a container it then depends on your screen size. Assuming you have the default settings a col-xs-12 works out to

- x-small: between 1px and 34px depending on screen width
- small: 32.5px
- medium: 50.8333px
- large: 67.5px

The calculation comes out simply to `(container width - (number of columns * (gutter width * 2))) / number of columns`